# How would I add a WHERE clause to a SQL or Access Data Source in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I am evaluating Power BI as a possible tool for publication quality reports that will be distributed to clients.  My source databases are in Microsoft SQL and Access.

I am somewhat confused by the Power Query Editor.

- As a part of this, we will need to be able to specify the value of a Client Id field and apply a WHERE clause to the SQL and Access data source.
- I see that I can filter data on one or more columns. This would be cumbersome if generating reports for a set of individual clients.
- I see a Manage Parameters feature on the Home Tab of the Power Query Editor. Can these parameters be compared to values in database tables?
- Are there examples of using M or DAX (or anything else) to implement an equivalent WHERE clause?
- Do I have to run stored procedures, populate temporary tables and then run Power BI reports?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few options:

1. Connect to your database using a [Native Database Query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-data-from-a-database-using-native-database-query-power-query-f4f448ac-70d5-445b-a6ba-302db47a1b00). (Related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675504/edit-sql-in-power-query).)
2. Connect to a view you create on your database that includes the WHERE clause.
3. Filter the table in the Query Editor after connecting to it.
4. Import or [DirectQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-use-directquery) the whole table and filter at run time.

In #3, basic filtering usually gets [folded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-folding) into the under-the-hood query that Power BI sends to the database so that this is similar to #1 as far as your database sees.

With #4, it's possible to apply [row-level security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls) so that different people have access to different subsets of the data.